# Unable to run fastlane sigh. "Couldn't download certificate"

Tags: ios, build, fastlane

For some reason I'm getting `Couldn't download certificate, got this instead: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed` whenever I run sigh or fastlane. I tried skipping skip_certificate_verification or skip_fetch_profiles but it still doesn't work. It was working yesterday. Has Apple Developer Portal been changed or updated today?

Is anyone also getting this?

Here's the exact error I got:

`` /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spaceship-0.21.1/lib/spaceship/portal/portal_client.rb:311:in `download_certificate': [!] Couldn't download certificate, got this instead: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed (Spaceship::Client::UnexpectedResponse) ``

Thanks

Comment: Good question. Also getting this.

Comment: Also getting this. So seems like an API change on Apple's side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the issues list on [Sigh](https://github.com/fastlane/sigh/issues/270), you just need to update: `sudo gem update spaceship`

Answer (score 4):

Haha spaceship v0.22.0 fixed it. Thanks KrauseFx!